# jquery, how to use trigger?

Tags: php, jquery

i have this situation:

```
if(isset($_POST["sm"]) {
    print "<br><div id=\"redirect\">success</div>";
}
```

in javascript i have:

```
$('#redirect').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
```

what happens is that if the form is submitted that div shows up for two seconds then faced out, but i also want to trigger a click by using: `$('#test').trigger('click');`

how can i connect them together so that when the div shows i also trigger the click.

also i cant use javascript inside the php if statement

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
$("#redirect").fadeOut("2000", function(){
                $('#test').trigger('click');
            });
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. the fade is working but not the trigger